# Hide Button from RecyclerView from outside activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility, android-button

I have created a chat app that uses `RecyclerView` in order to create the messages.

The activity where all of the chat actions are is called `ChatActivity`.

In some cases, the `RecyclerView` creates a message that contains a `Confirm` button.

[image]

The button have a `listener` to the `RecyclerView` and it all works.

I would like that once a user clicked on `Confirm`, that the `visibility` of the button will be set to `GONE`.

I tried to add inside my click listener the following, however it did not hide the buttons.

```
ChatAdapter.OnConfirmClickListener confirmListener = new ChatAdapter.OnConfirmClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(Button confirmB) {

        Log.d( "ERROR", "error" );

        DocumentReference IsConfirmed = db.collection( "Chats" ).document( chatID );
        IsConfirmed
                .update( "ConfirmedFlag", auth.getUid() )
                .addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        Button confirm = findViewById( R.id.Confirm );
                        confirm.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                        Log.d( "WHAT", "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!" );

                    }
                } )
                .addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w( "WHAT", "Error updating document", e );
                    }
                } );


    }
};
```

Any reason that it is not working? I thought maybe there is a problem with `View`?

Also, maybe because it was created inside the adapter, it is impossible to set `visibility` to `GONE` but im not sure.

Thank you

Comment: Do you call find view by id again ????? so how does the user click on that for confirm message??

Answer (score 1):

Instead:

```
Button confirm = findViewById( R.id.Confirm );
confirm.setVisibility( View.GONE );
```

Replace with this:

```
confirmB.setVisibility( View.GONE );
```

I hope to be useful

Comment: I get an error saying Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference when I do so.